# PhoneGap redirect to login after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm running the code below to check if the user still has a session ID immediately when the app is opened.  If not, I want to redirect to the login page.  The problem is, I get an intense flickering.  If i change it to document.ready then the splash screen stays there forever without ever loading the app.  How can I correctly do this?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem("sessionid2")){
        window.location = "login.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: Tell me are you using some kind of MVC technology?  If not you will need to change your logic because this will not work correctly, but you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put it in your onDeviceReady?

Also best practise would to be keeping everything on the one page, rather then redirecting to another html page losing all your js variables.